# How To make Raspberry Pi Hardware PWM off after startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, pwm

I am driving motor using ESC with Hardware PWM signal comes from Raspberry Pi ,I set the **GPIO 19 (PIN 35)** to be **PWM1** , **the problem is when the Raspberry Pi startup it gives output value to PWM1 (GPIO 19)** which causing the motor to start spinning at slow speed ,
**How can stop that ? I want GPIO 19 to stop sending signal after the startup , unless I do it my self .**

NOTE : when the PWM was disabled in (/boot/config.txt) the GPIO 19 was Input ,so its wasn't sending any signal ,But after activating the PWM1 it changed to ALT5 and start giving signal just after startup.
[image]